# Django / Ajax not refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I have built a Save button. The user clicks the "Save" button to save a record to their collection. This changes the "Save" button text to "Saved". The user can then click on "Saved" to unsave the record.

The user can Save the record succesfully and the ajax updates the html as expected by changing `id="likes"` to `id="unsave"`.

The issue is that the ajax is not picking up the id="unsave" so is not routing to the `unsave_release` URL, it is routing to the `save_release` URL.

Url examples

http://127.0.0.1:8000/save_release/?release_id=585197&num_saves=14
http://127.0.0.1:8000/unsave_release/?release_id=585197&num_saves=14

Do I need to reset the ajax in some way after the user makes the initial Save?

**Models.py**

```py
@login_required
def save_release(request):

    release_id = None
    num_saves = None
    username = request.user.username
    if request.method == 'GET':
        release_id = request.GET['release_id']
        num_saves = request.GET['num_saves']

    if release_id:

        insert = ChartsExtended(release_id=release_id,artist=username,url='Like',date='date',type='U',source='net')
        insert.save()
        num_saves = str(int(num_saves) + 1)
        return HttpResponse(num_saves)

@login_required
def unsave_release(request):

    release_id = None
    num_saves = None
    username = request.user.username
    if request.method == 'GET':
        release_id = request.GET['release_id']
        num_saves = request.GET['num_saves']

    if release_id:

        insert = ChartsExtended.objects.get(release_id=release_id,artist=username)
        insert.delete()
        num_saves = str(int(num_saves) - 1)
        return HttpResponse(num_saves)
```

**ajax.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

        // JQuery code to be added in here.
        $('#likes').click(function(){
            var release_id;
            var num_saves;
            release_id = $(this).attr("data-releaseid");
            num_saves = $(this).attr("data-numsaves")
            $.get('/save_release/', {release_id: release_id,num_saves: num_saves}, 

                function(data){

                $('#like_count').html(data + " people saved this");

                // $('#likes').css({"background-color":"#FF0000"});

                $('#likes').toggleClass("btn-info");
                $('#likes').text('Saved!')
                $('#likes').attr('id','unsave');
            });
        });

        //this unsaves a release from Release
        $('#unsave').click(function(){
            var release_id;
            var num_saves;
            release_id = $(this).attr("data-releaseid");
            num_saves = $(this).attr("data-numsaves")
            $.get('/unsave_release/', {release_id: release_id,num_saves: num_saves}, 

                function(data){

                $('#like_count').html(data + " people saved this");

                // $('#likes').css({"background-color":"#FF0000"});

                $('#unsave').toggleClass("btn-success");
                $('#unsave').text('Save')
                $('#unsave').attr('id','likes');
            });
        });
```

**release.html**

```
<h3 id="like_count">{{dict_item.cnt}} people saved this</h3>


  <p><button id="likes" data-releaseid="{{ dict_item.id }}" data-numsaves="{{dict_item.cnt}}" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-success release-follow-buttons" type="button">Save</button></p>
```

which transforms into the following after the user clicks Save

```
<p><button id="unsave" data-releaseid="release_id" data-numsaves="num_saves" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-success release-follow-buttons btn-info" type="button">Saved!</button></p>
```

**urls.py**

```py
url(r'^save_release/$', views.save_release, name='save_release'),
url(r'^unsave_release/$', views.unsave_release, name='unsave_release'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you are attaching the `onclick` handler on the element with the id `unsave`, which at that time doesn't exist and the handler isn't attached.

You either need to attach the handler, when you change the `id` or a better solution would be if you use [delegated event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(document).on("click", "#likes", function() {
    // code
});
$(document).on("click", "#unsave", function() {
    // code
});
```

You also don't need to attach these delegated events in your `ready` callback, because it isn't necessary for `#likes` and `#unsave` elements to exist when you do that.